# How can I get Screw.Unit to Run on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, screwunit

Using the repo found here:

http://github.com/nkallen/screw-unit

and this commit:

cc41f3cf373d804b11519704faf1971370f43760

I get this screen when viewing the package's "EXAMPLE.html" file:

[image]

Basically all of the text showing how many tests were run and the describe/it clauses, and the test results are missing.

The same revision works fine on Safari and Firefox.

I found this report that seems related, but no follow-up:

http://groups.google.com/group/screw-unit/browse_thread/thread/f0e82f5d68acbf21

Any ideas?

Edit: I found that upgrading jquery from version 1.2.6 (included with package) to 1.4.2 results in a screen in which green/red tests show up. Unfortunately, the top header showing the number of total tests and failing tests does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble and use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/). It runs on all browsers, offers custom matchers, works on all browsers, is offered by [Pivotal Labs](http://pivotallabs.com/), and is wicked fast. Syntax is very close to Screw.Unit, so porting is not conceptually difficult.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be hitting the same problem, I've found that the [Pivotal branch of Screw.Unit](http://github.com/pivotal/screw-unit) seems to give exactly the same output for EXAMPLE.html in both IE7 and FF. There are [others to choose from as well](http://github.com/pivotal/screw-unit/network).